# google maps markers with google analytics onclick event in variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-analytics

I've set up a site with a google map with markers. All the info (name, address, email, url) is entered by the editors of the website.
http://oktamsterdam.nl/google-map-op-homepage/

To create markers I put all markerinfo in a variable

```
locaties = [
['Ouder- en Kindteam Centrum', '52.38022', '4.88348', '<h3>Ouder- en Kindteam Centrum</h3><a href="tel:0205555961"  onclick="ga(\x27send\x27, \x27event\x27, \x27Index\x27, \x27tel\x27, \x270205555961\x27);" >020 555 5961</a><br />Open: ma &#8211; vr van 8.30 – 17.00'],
['Ouder en Kindteam West', '52.37791', '4.84876', '<h3>Ouder en Kindteam West</h3><a href="mailto:bosenlommer@oktamsterdam.nl"  onclick="ga(\x27send\x27, \x27event\x27, \x27Index\x27, \x27mailto\x27, \x27bosenlommer@oktamsterdam.nl\x27);" >bosenlommer@oktamsterdam.nl</a><p>&nbsp;</p><a href="tel:0205555961"  onclick="ga(\x27send\x27, \x27event\x27, \x27Index\x27, \x27tel\x27, \x270205555961\x27);" >020 555 5961</a>']
];
```

To make sure quotes and double quotes don't get mixed up I user \x27, but the company that handles all Google Analytics tell me nothing is coming in (All 'normal' onclick event are, like

`<a href="mailto:info@oktamsterdam.nl"  onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Index', 'mailto', 'info@oktamsterdam.nl');" >info@oktamsterdam.nl</a>`

are)

Does anyone has a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say to use the single quotes rather than encoding them to \x27, and be consistent with the single quotes so you don't need to worry about mixing them up.

Answer (score 1):

I have used single quote in my case and it works. You can follow this:

```
'<a href="' + url + '" onclick="_ga.push([\'track\', \'Download\', \'' + title + '\', \'format\']);">Download</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks Beroza, I'll try this out and hope the analytics guys are happy with this.